# Personalizar cursor en mi pagina web

Tags: php, html, css, css3, cursor

Deseo cambiar el cursor de mi pagina web, pero sin éxito.

He buscado, 'cacharreando' y esto es lo que hice en la sección de css:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://pm1.narvii.com/6889/d2d9b7ffb36fafc8030e94c2f920cada3b84e870r1-1200-675v2_hq.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=89747), url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=89747), default;
  cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=89747) 5 10, url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=89747) 5 10, pointer;
  cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=89747);
}
```

Como pueden ver, tiene también un fondo personalizado. El fondo funciona a la perfección, sin embargo, el cursor no me funciona. No se personaliza :(. Necesito al menos el puntero por defecto, la animación del dragoncito o un tipo *ani*, o *cur* de un dragón.... Algo.... He revisado también las preguntas de este sitio y sin suerte :(

Estoy usando *XAMMP* y he probado con *Firefox*, *Chrome* y *Opera*...  Muchas gracias por su atención :D

Pdta, existe la posibilidad de descargarlo y solo llamarlo al directorio pero así no me funciona a la hora de subirlo en un hosting, por eso opto mejor la opcion de llamarlo desde una Url

Comment: El formato que usas, .ANI es un formato para definir cursores en Windows, no es un formato de imagen que puedas visualizar en la web, el único que soporta .ANI es IE. PD: No somos un foro :)

Answer (score 6):

Veo varios problemas. El primero de todos, es que estás sobreescribiendo la propiedad `cursor` varias veces. No sé lo que pretendes con eso, pero al hacerlo va a prevalecer la última de las 3 que tienes, quedando las anteriores anuladas.

Lo segundo que veo es que estás pasándole a *cursor* la ruta de una imagen en un formato que no soporta (*ANI*).

> Pueden usarse todos los formatos gráficos soportados por Gecko. Por lo
>   tanto puede usar imágenes PNG, JPG, CUR, GIF, etc. Sin embargo, ANI no
>   está soportado. Además, si especifica un GIF animado, el cursor usará
>   el GIF, pero sin animación. Esta limitación podría ser superada en
>   futuras versiones.

Y para finalizar, la imagen que le pases tiene que tener un tamaño inferior a 128x128 (esto último no he podido comprobarlo a ciencia cierta, lo que está claro es que si le pasas una imagen grande se va a ir por el *default* del segundo parámetro que le pasas a `cursor`, que en mi caso es *pointer*)

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional: **Enjoy eat**

```css
body {
    background: url(https://pm1.narvii.com/6889/d2d9b7ffb36fafc8030e94c2f920cada3b84e870r1-1200-675v2_hq.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: url(https://www.mcdonalds.es/sites/all/themes/macdo/image/img-logo-footer.png), pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

**Referencia:** https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/Uso_de_URL_como_valor_de_la_propiedad_cursor

Comment: Como observación, al tener varias imágenes dentro de la propiedad cursor, va a usarse la primera en ser llamada (si es que existe). También, el tamaño máximo (al menos en Gecko y Webkit) para una imagen de cursor es de 128×128px

Comment: Gracias, las medidas máximas que encontré yo entonces deben de ser erroneas. No obstante edito mi pregunta para dejar el link a modo de referencia.

Comment: @Marcos Editada la respuesta para completarla con tu sugerencia. Gracias ^^

Comment: es un poco extraño esto, pero lo del 128px lo encontré en tu mismo enlace, pero en la versión inglesa: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

Comment: Yo añadiría una regla para que el puntero se mantenga en los elementos con :hover, como enlaces: `*:hover {
            cursor: url(https://www.mcdonalds.es/sites/all/themes/macdo/image/img-logo-footer.png), pointer;
        }` Otra cosa que no veo que acabe de funcionar: cuando ejecutas el ejemplo a pantalla completa, la parte inferior de la pantalla, el puntero deja de ser custom. Donde pones la altura, puede funcionar mejor: `height: 100vh;`

Comment: @Orici El OP tiene puesto el puntero custom en el `<body>` quizás lo quiera también custom en los enlaces. Atenta contra la usabilidad pero no sé lo que tiene el OP en mente, no conozco su escenario no me meto en eso. Para lo segundo que comentas, ocurre porque forcé un tamaño de 500px para el `<body>` a fin de mostrarlo aunque no tenga un contenido que le de "altura". Es solo para ejemplificar, en un caso real no haría falta ese `height`.

Comment: @phpMyGuel estaba probando lo del cursor en local, y la parte inferior de la página no aparece el personalizado... por más que cambie la altura o asocie el puntero a todos los elementos del documento. Ni in chrome, ni firefox, no se si abrir otra pregunta... Tengo por ejemplo un *footer*, en el inspector de propiedades si aparece como activa la regla para el cursor, dentro del mismo, pero no se renderiza... no es por el footer, es la parte inferior de la pantalla.

Comment: @Orici Algo rato tienes que tener, porque de ser tu elemento *footer* hijo de `<body>` debería heredar el puntero, a no ser que lo estés sobrescribiendo. Con gusto puedo echarle un vistazo a tu código si montas una pregunta ^^

Comment: @phpMyGuel esta publicada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/340109