# Cursor personalizado no renderiza en la parte inferior de la ventana

Tags: html, css

Haciendo pruebas sobre este ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333741/20709 respuesta a pregunta una relacionada, me he dado cuenta de que en la parte inferior de la pantalla, no se renderiza la imagen dada al cursor.

Probado en *Chrome* y *Firefox*, en **Ubuntu** con una pantalla de 15.7 pulgadas. El area donde no se renderiza coincide en el siguiente código con la altura que le he dado al `footer`, pero puede darse más altura a este para ver que no es el propio elemento:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom cursor</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        *,*:before,*:after{-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center}
        *{color:#1A1A1A}body{height:100vh;}html{font-size:calc(5px+1vw)}img{height:auto;width:100%}

        *,
        *:hover 
        footer:hover {
            cursor: url(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7187599/77756881-63016b80-7030-11ea-91a5-b49489cf43b7.png), pointer;
        }
        footer {
            height: 8vh;
        }
        p {
            margin: 1rem auto;
        }
        .content {
            background: grey;
            height: 92vh;
            padding: 5%;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error eos hic, accusantium dolorum cupiditate facilis expedita porro magni. Incidunt aperiam, officiis esse ex fugiat alias voluptas, accusamus provident velit ut?</p>

        <a href="https://pngtree.com/">Arma PNG diseñado por 588ku de Pngtree.com</a>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione voluptatem molestias nesciunt totam et, iure unde nobis ipsa explicabo? Alias ullam hic quasi velit id nihil eaque reiciendis consectetur nulla.</p>
    </div>
    <footer>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum officia ut repellat rerum provident quaerat iusto, nemo sequi tempore nihil eveniet perferendis cupiditate consequatur aperiam nam nisi reprehenderit deserunt autem.</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hasta donde he podido comprobar esto se debe al tamaño de la imagen del puntero. En el momento de que esta excede uno de los bordes del **layout** lo sustituye por el default porque al ser más pequeño este no se sale todavía. Si te fijas también sucede con los bordes izquierdos y derecho. Con el superior no sucede porque el puntero, aunque sea una imagen, realmente está posicionado arriba a la izquierda de la propia imagen.

Comment: Añado que tampoco sucede en el borde izquierdo por eso mismo, porque al estar realmente el puntero alojado en el la esquina superior izquierda, cuando la imagen comienza a salirse es porque el puntero también se sale, por lo que la imagen se queda chocando con el borde izquierdo de la pantalla.

Comment: @phpMyGuel parece un poco problemático si quieres que sea el único cursor visible